# Ubuntu + GNOME HiDPI Cursor Size

Tags: gnome, dpi

I've used the GNOME Tweak Tool to set scaling to 2x, and it seems to work almost everywhere, except for my cursor on system toolbars, and I can't figure out why. [This imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg5OI.jpg) shows what I'm talking about.

Thanks!